# How to create a pkg installer with a custom action?

Tags: macos, package-management

I have created pkg bundle with pkgbuild & productbuild and I want to get the IP address from the User and that should be passed to postinstall script to write it in a specific file. I don't see any reference to do that. Can any one help me on this.

Comment: Why don't you do it on 1st run instead... & why do you think you need to hard-code a variable such as IP address, which could be constantly changing?

Comment: Hi Tet,Yes, it will be changing based on customer configuration.

Answer (score 5):

Ideally you want to avoid custom user interface elements within modern installer packages on macOS.

Where possible, fit your needs into the built-in options provided by the Installer. Alternatively, place the requirements into a supporting tool or first run sequence of any installed application.

## Installer Plug-in

If you must use a custom Installer plug-in, the latest Xcode continues to include a template project to get you started. Know that this route will be expensive in terms of development time and effort; additionally it is unlikely to be supported in future versions of the operating system.

Create a new plug-in in Xcode using the menu item:

**Xcode.app > File > Project… > macOS / Installer Plug-in**

The project includes a template for you to customise. In particular, take a look at the source code of the `InstallerPane` class. The header file contains comments and insight into how to subclass the class.

### Examples and Documentation

The [plug-in tutorial](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Stuff/Installer/Installer_Plugins/index.html) by Stéphane Sudre looks like a great resource.

Another good resource is the [Installer Developer mailing list](https://lists.apple.com/archives/installer-dev/) archive.

## Showing End User Licence Agreements

If you need to show an End User Licence Agreements (EULA) in your installer, use the built-in [license](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/DistributionDefinitionRef/Chapters/Distribution_XML_Ref.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005370-CH100-SW5) entry in the package's [distribution definition file](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/DistributionDefinitionRef/Chapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005370-CH1-SW1).

Where more than one EULA is required, concatenate the licences into one document.

Comment: Adding custom page is to get the user input. How can I get the user inputs and pass it to installer postinstall script?

Comment: I am not aware of any method to do this. Reconsider using an Installer plug-in and instead place the logic within a set-up application or tool.

Comment: @GrahamMiln Why you say that custom elements should be avoided ideally?

Comment: Apple is tending towards security over functionality. Installer plug-ins are arbitrary code running in an insecure environment. Apple could do the work to make custom plug-ins more secure or they could just drop support for plug-ins entirely and tell you to perform the task within a code-signed and notarised application. Which do you think is more likely? :-) Also the lack of maintained documentation is a hint of Installer plug-in's state.

Comment: @fsinisi90 I agree with Graham. I've tried doing things with installer packages that are off the beaten path, and it's painful. The support for it just isn't there, even if what you want to do *may* be possible. Better to look for another way, in my opinion.

Comment: What about an installer that doesn't do doing crazy things? I need to show two EULAs. Would you recommend to create it with the [Packages](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Packages/about.html) app and a plug-in?

Comment: I have updated the answer to address showing EULAs.

Comment: So let's see if I got it right: Using the Packages app (for example) to create an installer it's ok as long as plug-ins are not added?

Comment: You can use Packages.app but you should prefer Apple's `pkgbuild` and `productbuild` tools. Packages.app *should* produce the same output as Apple's tools but is easier to use. Consider investing the time now to get Apple's tools working for you to ensure longevity in your workflow.